# How do I detect loss of connection from a web socket in my Swift App

Tags: swift, websocket, urlsession

I am trying to detect loss of connection to my web socket in Swift. I have very little understanding of web sockets but I have tried googling for information but with little success. Here is my custom class providing a web socket service;

```
//
//  Services.swift
//  BetVictorTask
//
//  Created by Stephen Learmonth on 28/02/2022.
//

import UIKit

protocol NetworkServicesDelegateProtocol: AnyObject {
    func sendStockInfo(stocksInfo: [String: StockInfo])
}

class NetworkServices: NSObject, URLSessionWebSocketDelegate {
    
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkServices()
    
    var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask?
    
    var stocksInfo: [String: StockInfo] = [:]
    
    var socketResults: [String: [StockInfo]] = [:]
    
    weak var delegate: NetworkServicesDelegateProtocol?
    
    func fetchStockInfo(symbols: [String], delegate: CompanyPriceListVC) {
        
        self.delegate = delegate
        
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        webSocketTask = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: FINNHUB_SOCKET_STOCK_INFO_URL!)
                
        webSocketTask!.resume()
        
        for symbol in symbols {
            
            let string = FINNHUB_SOCKET_MESSAGE_STRING + symbol + "\"}"
            
            let message = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(string)
            
            webSocketTask!.send(message) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error sending message: \(error)")
                }
                
                self.receiveMessage()
                
            }
        }
    }
            
    private func receiveMessage() {
        
        self.webSocketTask!.receive { result in
                    
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error receiving message: \(error)")
                
            case .success(.string(let jsonData)):

                guard let stockData = jsonData.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
                
                self.socketResults = [:]
                self.stocksInfo = [:]
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let socketData = try decoder.decode(SocketData.self, from: stockData)
                    guard let stockInfoData = socketData.data else { return }
                    for stockInfo in stockInfoData {
                        let symbol = stockInfo.symbol
                        if self.socketResults[symbol] == nil {
                            self.socketResults[symbol] = [StockInfo]()
                        }
                        self.socketResults[symbol]?.append(stockInfo)
                    }
                    
                    for (symbol, stocks) in self.socketResults {
                        for item in stocks {
                            if self.stocksInfo[symbol] == nil {
                                self.stocksInfo[symbol] = item
                            } else if item.timestamp > self.stocksInfo[symbol]!.timestamp {
                                self.stocksInfo[symbol] = item
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    self.delegate?.sendStockInfo(stocksInfo: self.stocksInfo)
                    
                    self.receiveMessage()
                    
                } catch {
                    print("Error converting JSON: \(error)")
                }
                
            default:
                print("default")
            }
        }
    }

    func closeWebSocketConnection() {
        webSocketTask?.cancel(with: .goingAway, reason: nil)
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) {
        print("Got here")
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        guard let error = error as? URLError else { return }
        
        print("got here")
        
        
    }
    
    func fetchCompanyInfo(symbol: String, completion: @escaping (CompanyInfo?, UIImage?)->()) {
        
        let urlString = FINNHUB_HTTP_COMPANY_INFO_URL_STRING + symbol + "&token=" + FINNHUB_API_TOKEN
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching company info: \(error)")
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            do {
                let companyInfo = try decoder.decode(CompanyInfo.self, from: data)
                
                guard let logoURL = URL(string: companyInfo.logo) else { return }
                
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: logoURL) { data, response, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error fetching logo image: \(error)")
                    }
                    guard let data = data else { return }
                    
                    guard let logoImage = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
                    
                    completion(companyInfo, logoImage)
                    
                }
                task.resume()
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
                completion(nil, nil)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I have tried implementing;

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) {
        print("Got here")
    }
```

and then run the app and turn off WiFi to simulate loss of connection but the urlSession method never gets called.

How can I simulate loss of web socket connection while running my app and detect this disconnection. Also I need to think of a way to reconnect the web socket

Comment: To get started, look at NWPathMonitor to be notified when the entire network connection is completely gone (such as when you turned off wifi). Beyond that, it's very often not possible to know that you've lost a particular connection. The only way to know that a network connection exists is to send a packet and receive a packet in response. A connection that is currently passing no packets looks *exactly* like a connection that is broken. You cannot know, without sending a packet, whether a packet will be delivered. You can only know it won't even be tried by watching NWPathMonitor.

Comment: Generally, the solution is to periodically send a "ping" message (some command that does nothing except return a response). If the ping times out, then you assume that the connection is gone. A ping timing out does not mean the connection is *actually* gone. It may have been sent, but you got no response, or it may just take longer than the timeout. Connections are not tin cans with string between them. They're two people sending mail through the post office.

Comment: @RobNapier I have tried using NWPathMonitor but it doesn't report a disconnection status when I turn off the WiFi connection. I set it up in my code according to HackingWithSwift. It reports that the connection is sound when I turn off the WiFi which is really odd. I have included ping code as well but it stops pinging when I turn off the Wifi. I don't get it.

Comment: The ping behavior is precisely as expected, so I expect you have a bug in your NWPathMonitor code. You should show that. There are several easy mistakes to make there.